# Are you missing reference?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-upgrade

I am upgrading MOSS2007 solution to SP2013. Everything is fine When I am building the solution at that time it is building successgully.
But when I am trying to publish the solution at that time it is throwing following error:

***The type or namespace name 'xxx' does not exist in the namespace 'xxx' (are you missing an assembly reference?)***

I have tried many things but no luck.
Is there any solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have created your solution you may find that you have built the solution on a environment where a certain DLL exists.

Realistically what you need to do is look at your error message and look in to what DLL contains the namespace that the error is giving you the error and check that the DLL exists on all Web servers, Possibly app server(depending on farm set up)

Cheers
Truez